# building libsox for iOS question

Tags: iphone, sox

I want to build libsox for iphone device but I havent got any luck doing so. I am just wondering if it is even possible to build this library for iphone....

Comment: Well i first tried by building it with the script build_for_iphone.sh. It works for the simulator version but for the device it doesnt seem to recognize the architecture of the lib file. I have checked the lib file with lipo and confirmed that it was armv6... so yeah i am lost what to do...

Comment: Samuel, 

could you please share us the info that where you found the build_for_iphone.sh script..

Thanks,

Tarum

Comment: http://pseudogreen.org/blog/build_autoconfed_libs_for_iphone.html you can get it from here

Answer (score 4):

einsteinx already posted from my blog ;) but here both links again

First post explains how you build libsox:
http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-making-it-a-framework

The second explains how to use it:
http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-doing-effects

please up the answer if it helped you! thanks!

Comment: i fixed the links on my blog :)

Answer (score 3):

http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-making-it-a-framework

^ This is a great guide to build a libsox framework for iOS. Just place the script in the libsox source folder and run it. It builds a universal framework that works on arm6 (old iphone and ipod touch), arm7 (new iphone, ipod touch, and ipad), and i386 (simulator).

Answer (score 1):

Basically lib sox library support for audio with some default formats. If we need more audio format support we need to compile required audio format library as per the requirement.

Eg: Wav - Default for in lib sox

Eg: mp3 - Need to compile libmp3

Yes of course!!!.We cannot compile the libsox for iOS Simulator and iOS phone at single time. Because of simulator and iOS device contains different architectures.

Simulator arch - xi386 , x64

iPhone arch - armv6, armv7 , arm64

So, While compiling we mentioned / enabled the simulator arch mean whole compilation will compile based on the simulator. Because all supporting files and libs generated first enabled architecture. Finally we have to compile both simulator and ios device separately after that can use in ios development.

If want to be single library , we need to merge the both simulator and device libs by using libo tool via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I have got it built now... it seems that if i build for the simulator first then device it is not able to compile for the device. I have done this again with just the device only and it works now... strange indeed...

Answer (score 0):

A latest version is available [here](https://github.com/KelvinJin/libsox-iOS). Both build script and prebuilt library are available.