# Transcoding Audio on iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, audio, ffmpeg

I'm grabbing song data from the iOS music library (as an `NSData` object), but when the data is not that of an MP3 file, I'd like to transcode it.

I have two questions about the transcoding process:

1. Is there something built in to do, say M4A to MP3 transcoding, or will I have to use something like ffmpeg or other external libraries? If the latter, are there any examples of doing this on iOS knocking about?
2. What's the best way to do this that doesn't load everything into memory? Obviously a large song file will exhaust the memory and the app will be terminated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can't you just play it as is? If you're going to do something other than play it, I doubt Apple will allow it.

Comment: I'm not too worried about Apple allowing it, I've no plans to use it in a commercial product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>maybe [libSOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/libsox.html) fits to your needs.</strike>

the features of the tool are available [here][2]

to compile for iOS, check out the thread [building libsox for iOS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708177/building-libsox-for-ios-question)

[2]: http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features "here"

---

i think ffmpeg is the choice

for iOS http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-October/076618.html

---

http://fobs.sourceforge.net/ is another choice (C++ wrapper to FFMPEG). Its home page has a reference to m4a files. To use it you could wrap up C++ in Objective-C in a .mm file.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there's no mention of it being able to handle m4a files, even mp3 appears to need additional libraries.

Comment: Yeah, you just gave me a link to ffmpeg here, didn't really answer either of the questions.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer if nothing better comes along, until then, I'm waiting for something in a little more detail and that answers my second question. Out of interest, have you experience in audio trancoding, or have you just used Google to find these links?

Comment: Not by programming but using cmd and GUI tools in K-Lite Mega Codec Pack. I have also been successful in running a C++ math parser library on iOS by compiling it for ARM architecture (which was intended for x86-64)

Answer (score 0):

How about LAME + libsndfile?

See:

http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/doc/html/index.html

http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/